# PDF.jsで暗号化PDFを描画したい

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, html5-canvas

#### 前提

Webアプリケーションを構築しています。
JavaScriptを使用し、ブラウザでPDFを表示する機能が必要になったため
JavaScriptでPDFを表示可能なPDF.jsを使用し、技術調査を行っています。

PDF.jsでは以下の2通りの描画形式があることを認識しております。

1. PDF.jsに搭載されているビューワ（viewer.html）を利用しiframeにて描画
2. pdfjs を埋め込んで、PDF を SVG や canvas 要素に変換する

ビューワに備えられているズームやしおり、印刷機能をそのまま流用したいため
1の方法にて対応することを考えております。

通常のPDFファイルに関しては、問題なく描画出来ることは確認しました。

しかし、描画を行いたいと思っているPDFはパスワードにて暗号化されたファイルになります。
暗号化されたファイルをそのまま描画した場合、パスワードを入力するモーダルが表示されます。

#### 実現したいこと

暗号化されたPDFファイルを上記の１の方法で描画する際に、JavaScriptサイドでパスワードを指定し、パスワードの入力するモーダルを表示させないで、描画を行いと思っております。
⇒同一アプリで発行したパスワードでPDFを作成しているので、そのままシステム側でパスワードの解除を行いたい

２の方法においては、PDF.jsのメソッドでgetDocument()の引数にパスワードを指定することで暗号化されたPDFファイルを描画可能なことは確認したのですが、PDFビューワ機能を利用したいので、1の方法でどうにかパスワードを指定しPDFを開くことは出来ないかと考えております。

どなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

PDF.js Stable (v2.16.105)

※ [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/401g93p9ak93xf) でも同様の質問をさせて頂いております。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[How to Open a Password Protected PDF with Javascript using PDF.JS](https://usefulangle.com/post/22/pdfjs-tutorial-2-viewing-a-password-protected-pdf), [pdf.js/src/display/api.js#L509](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/4e58dabb3274941345d93b058676691f5f5bccfd/src/display/api.js#L509)

Comment: @kunif 情報提供ありがとうございます。私もこちらは拝見致しました。方法２の場合で実現する際にはこちらのやり方で出来そうなのですが、方法１のviewer.htmlで暗号化ファイルを解除した状態で表示するというのが中々文献がなく困っているところです…

Comment: こちらのIssue [how to use password in the iframe? #8631](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8631) にビューアーをカスタマイズする助言(だけ、具体的な方法はなし)があり, こちらのセクション [Can I specify a different PDF in the default viewer?](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-i-specify-a-different-pdf-in-the-default-viewer) の3つ目の段落？に生のバイナリを渡す方法(You can use raw binary data to open a PDF document:) という記述があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。iframeのタグにパスワード埋め込みで対応出来ないと認識しました。仰って頂いている通りViewer.htmlへ生データを渡して表示が出来る方法を探ってみたいと思います。